# Creating parallel lines at particular distance from lines which are part of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am using QGIS 2.18 . I have shapefile which contains multiple lines. After processing certain data processing , I need to draw parallel lines at different distances from existing lines. For example I have 32 lines in existing shapefile. I want to draw parallel lines at distance of 50, 100, 170, 500,400 from line ID no. 3 ,6,20,25,31 in one go. Is there any method or plugin in QGIS for doing same?

Answer (score 7):

You may use the [**QAD**](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) plugin, which offers CAD-like commands in QGIS.

It only works with Projected Coordinate Systems (so you need to project your data before using it) and with editing mode enabled (right-click on the layer and select `Toggle Editing`).

For your case, you need to click on the **Offset** button:

[image]

and follow the instructions that will appear on the *QAD text window* (exactly as in AutoCAD):

[image]

For example, this is the output when using a different offset for two different features:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other method or plugin to do this task without projecting data?

Comment: I used an approach with projected data since it seemed you were dealing with meters (_distances of 50, 100, 170, 500,400.._). Changing projection is very simple: right-click on the layer, then `Save as` and finally select a Projected Coordinate System. Once you have performed the offset, you may turn back to the Geographic Coordinate System with the reverse operation... It should be correct.

Comment: Without projecting the data, you need to deal with angles instead of meters and I don't know if it becomes easier for you...

Comment: The QAD tool is working fine. But I have to repeat task for all the lines in shapefile manually. Is there any method to read line_ID and distance to line read from attribute table or exel or CSV file automatically  and draw all parallel lines simultaneously.

Comment: I don't know a tool which does this task, but I may try to give a solution using PyQGIS... Could it be of interest for you?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a column in your attribute table which specifies the distance between the parallel lines then the following method should be able to do it in one go -

You can use the `Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines` algorithm under `GDAL/OGR > [OGR] Geoprocessing` in the Processing toolbox. You will need to set the *Operation* as **Offset Curve** and enter the name of the column containing the distance in *Buffer distance* (In my case the name of the column is *width*). Also you can set which side of the line the parallel line should be drawn by selecting *Buffer side* as right or left.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using OGR tool as per your suggestion but nothing has been shown in new output shapefile.

Comment: Can you share the projection system your shape file is in? Screenshots of the output layer attribute table maybe helpful.

Comment: Projection system of shapefile is EPSG 4326

Comment: So you do understand that the new lines are created at a distance of 50,100,170,500 and 400 which is in the unit Degrees and not meters(which I am assuming you want?)

Comment: Assuming that you want the distance in meters - you'd have to convert your shapefile in a projection system with units in meters (for example a UTM projection system of the applicable zone). Then run the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now algorithm is working fine. I am getting parallel lines. Parallel line length is same as original line. Is there any method to change length of derived parallel line.

Answer (score 6):

You may use "v.parallel", you can found this tool in QGIS processing toolbox.

1. Select the line with line ID no. 3 ,6,20,25,31
   [image: Select lines]
2. Use "v.parallel", create parallel line from the selected lines. But, you have to do multiple times to produce different offset distances (50, 100, 170, 500,400). There is a option "Side", you can assigns the location of the parallel lines.
   [image: "v.parallel"]
3. Result: parallel lines (blue colored) at left side of the selected lines
   [image: result]

Comment: Thanks Cy Y for reply. I have used v.parallel command but nothing has been shown in new output shapefile.

Comment: p/s: "v.parallel" command only work with curved lines, it can't work to the straight lines which have only two line vertex.

Answer (score 1):

You can very simply create a parallel line in your QGIS plugin based on QgsGeometry.offsetCurve method.