# Multi copy / paste point shapefile with fixed offset

Tags: qgis-2.14

I'm looking for a tool in QGIS to copy a point location of a shapefile for multiple distances.

So, for example, the point location is on X/Y coordinate, 0,0. I want to have a copy of 4 extra points on coordinate: 0,10, 0,20, 0,30,0,40 in one time.

Is that possible in QGIS 2.14 or QGIS 2.18. I'm at the moment a 2.14 user. And is there a plugin to solve this problem, I did not find a good one (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins)?

I've looked at similar issues on gis.stackexchange but found only of offset for a single line (no multicopy).
[Creating parallel lines at particular distance from lines which are part of a shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229914/creating-parallel-lines-at-particular-distance-from-lines-which-are-part-of-a-sh)

Comment: Do you need also the attributes?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. If tihis is working i'm happy for now.