# Remove overlaps by moving overlapping features with a specific, scale-based delta

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, line, qgis-processing

I need to use QGIS to move multiple polylines for tracking data.

I want to move any overlapping feature to the left or right with a specific delta based on a scale.

I can do that with ArcMap using [parallel line copy](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/copying-parallel-line-features.htm), and I have searched how to do that with QGIS or Py-Qgis.

Do you know which lib or tool I must use?

Actually I don't have choice and I make processing on data. But a display solution can be a good idea because there is no data manipulation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating parallel lines at particular distance from lines which are part of a shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229914/creating-parallel-lines-at-particular-distance-from-lines-which-are-part-of-a-sh)

Comment: Do you actually want to create new geometries (which is what the ArcMap editing tool seems to do), or *display* the overlapping lines differently? How many exact overlaps do you typically have?

Comment: @Simbamangu two possibilities are acceptable but on ArcMap I don't have choice. I duplicate the overlaping data and delete old. Typically that will be 3 or 4 overlaps for same object dans 200 overlap objetct but i can add more overlap and partial overlap in specific case. I kwon A display solution exist for point but in my case that is not just a spread.