# Building zig-zag lines (Drone flight path)

Tags: qgis, line, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, parallel-lines

I need to create a line path like the one below.
I have to create a flight plan for an inspection with drone of a solar plant and I know the length of every single row and the distance between row, so I need a fast and automatic method to create the flight path.

There's any way to do that in QGIS using plugin or other function?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you trying to make a flight path that will have sufficient overlap for your drone camera to allow you to do Structure from Motion on those images, are you trying to map in QGIS an existing flight path, or are you just trying to make a nice graphic in QGIS?

Comment: I  need to create a line path like the one below. I have to create a flight plan for an inspection with drone of a solar plant and i know the lenght of every single row and the distance between row, so I need a fast and automatic method to create the flight path.

There's any way to do that in QGIS using plugin or other function?

Comment: Why are you not using a flight planning application like [Mission Planner](https://ardupilot.org/planner/) or [QGroundControl](http://qgroundcontrol.com/)? You can generate flight plans and export them to vector data. Those are open source.

Comment: I would use the v.parallel command to create a number of lines parallel to the first, then connect the ends of the lines by hand. This answer is helpful

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230159/119

Comment: In QGIS, add some opensource aerial imagery and manually 'heads-up' digitize your lines.  It will take a few minutes to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

There is now Qgis [flight planner](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/flight_planner/). I haven't used it but [the extended guide](https://github.com/JMG30/flight_planner/wiki/Guide) is detailed, which speaks to the level of effort put in to the plugin.

[image: grid pattern flight plan]