Repeating linestring across farm field at 40 inch intervals to use r.report for pixel values
I am a new user of QGIS. I have found answers to most of my issues. This one has me stuck. I have included an image of the project I am attempting to create.
My plan is to place a linestring on every row of this field. I need to be able to repeat the linestring every 40 inches. Right now I am using (copy and move feature) and this is taking a long time. I was thinking QGIS would have some kind of feature like CAD so I could offset, but I cannot find one.
Then I will use r.report to get the pixel values from the linestrings. Then use the report from r.report to calculate how many feet of pixels of each linestring are below a set pixel value. Then do a calculation based on that report to tell me how many plants are missing, or acres of plants are missing. This may not work because I am unsure of the linestring size. I know that my pixels are .049 by -.049 so it may not correlate with the linestring size.
I think the project FieldImageR was designed to do projects like this but I could not get it installed (lack of skills) on my part.
The ultimate goal is to know how many acres of plants are missing and how many acres are not. I already completed one project using pixel values of the whole field but then realized it would not give me the correct information. I am hoping this idea will.
Is there a better way to do this?


Does this help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229914/creating-parallel-lines-at-particular-distance-from-lines-which-are-part-of-a-sh ? You could put it into a model https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html and execute iteratively (40, 80, 120...) https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/processing/iterative.html

You can use the processing toolbox for that: there is a tool Array of offset (parallel) lineswhich will do the job for you. Just define the first line, the nummer of repeats and the distance between the lines.

